# Mounting Image into pendrive resulted in loss of size

Tags: format, usb-flash-drive

I have downloaded a image file of Chromium OS and mounted it into my pen drive (4GB) using Ultra ISO software. It occupied 2GB of my drive. Later I formatted the same in Windows using FAT32 but even then the size left on my pendrive is shown as 2GB.

Another strange thing I observed is that I am getting another file system called "exFAT" while I format which I didn't see any where before.

How can I format my pen drive removing the mounted Image and restoring back the total memory of the pen drive to be 4GB?

Comment: the best answer...as i asked the question and resolved the problem is to use HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool Worked at its best...and restored my space :) Thanks all for ur valuable replies

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using WIndows, take the following steps:

- Go to 'Config Panel' -> 'Administrative Tools' -> 'Computer Management'
- In this console go to 'Storage' -> 'Disc management'
- Locate your pendrive and remove all partitions on it by right-clicking them and choosing Remove.
- After you've done this, right-click the empty space and create a new partition, and format it as FAT or FAT32

You can now use the full capacity of your drive again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're on Windows here.

Right click on USB drive icon. Click 'Format'. (Quick Format is OK).

Done.

[Here's a guide](http://lifehacker.com/5195783/format-a-usb-drive-as-ntfs-in-windows-xp) for formatting a USB drive to NTFS in Windows XP. The same principles apply in other versions of Windows.

NB: exFAT is explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT).

NB: Formatting the USB drive will destroy all data on the USB drive. Make a back-up of any valuable data first (e.g. Chromium OS .iso).

Comment: The OP already told that he formatted the drive. My guess is the software he used to 'Mount' the image has actually created a partition on the USB drive, and has left a part of the drive unassigned. Formatting will not help in this case, you'll have to repartition the drive.

Comment: The question is a little clearer now it's been edited. I posted my answer a couple of minutes before the edit. That said, I'm still not very clear on what's being asked so I'll leave it to the pros.

Comment: I just saw the edited post. Now that I've read the non-edited version, I don't think you deserve that downvote, but I cannot remove it anymore...

Comment: @Roald: Not a problem.